# CSS Grid Layout разметка для таблицы

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.
хочу чтобы выводилось содержание 4 div в виде сетки

```
12
34
```

а выводиться строками

```
1
2
3
4
```

стиль

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 50px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
    width: 150px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item">some code</div>
  <div class="item">some code</div>
  <div class="item">some code</div>  
  <div class="item">some code</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример рабочий выводит 2 колонки и 2 ряда

Comment: в каком браузере тестируете?

Comment: в хроме. но ошибка была в лишнем теге я его не видел изначально